# How to use jQuery Ajax to pass multiple form values to php?

Tags: php, jquery

Why I can not get response from php by using jQuery Ajax?  When I click the "page" buttons, the weblink will change from:

```
 http://localhost/jQuery1.html
```

to something like:

```
http://localhost/jQuery1.html?state_chosen=Alabama&Type=&page=1
```

However, no echo-ed results from PHP.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"passdata.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
               $('#result').html(data);
            }  });
          });  });
     </script>

</head>
<body>

<form >
<select class="dd1" name="state_chosen">
<option selected value = ""> Location </option>
<option value="Alabama" > US: Alabama   </option>
</select>
<select class="dd2" name="type">
<option selected value = ""> Type </option>
<option value="Plumber" > Plumber   </option>
</select>

<button name="page" value="1" >1</button>
<button name="page" value="2" >2</button>   

</form>

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

passdata.php

```
<?php
echo '<div>' .$_POST['state_chosen']." <br>". $_POST['type']."<br>". $_POST['page']. '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Firstly this line is incorrect: `$(#'result').html(data);` the hash has to be inside the quote

Comment: You also have to prevent default or the form will submit

Comment: You're $_POST['type'] isn't going to match since you're echoing $_POST['type'] and the name attribute is 'Type'. Case doesn't match.

Comment: @RobertCathey, I changed "Type" to "type", the problem persists.

Comment: Yes. I didn't mean to imply that that would fix you're problem; I just meant that you also have that problem.

Comment: @Rasclatt, I fixed the typo to `$('#result').html(data);`  The problem still there.  About your 2nd comment, I don't understand how to "prevent default".  Could you give an example?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery should look something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Sorry, I put the form event in the (document) which is wrong.
    $("form").change(function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"passdata.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
               $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });

    // This will stop the form being submitted
    // form.preventDefault; Remove if you need submission

     });
});
</script>
```

Also, as mentioned by *@Robert Cathey*, check your `$_POST` on your `passdata.php` page. You will get an **Undefined index** error.

Comment: What I want is that the form be submitted whenever there is a change.

Comment: Ok, then `.change()` is what you need!

Comment: your code partially solved the problem.  Now I get responses when I change "state_chosen" or "type", together with an error message of `Notice: Undefined index: page in P:\XAMPP\htdocs\pathjobs\passdata.php on line 3`, as you predicted.  However, click on the "button" doesn't generate a response.

Comment: And, since you are not doing a submit, it may not be 100% necessary, depends on the effect you are trying to get, but if you click buttons in the form, it will reload the page as a `$_GET` (what you've described).

Comment: Yeah, that's what my comment is above. Clicking the button will prevent anything from happening. Also, if you don't want a big string of key/values in your URL, you need to add `method="post"` in your `<form>` tag

Comment: If the "button" doesn't function as I want, anything else (clickable and presented as 'page numbers') can fulfill the function?

Comment: You can do click events if you want to. Try removing the prevent first.

Answer (score 2):

I fully tested your code.

The error was just the extra semi-colon `;` after the closing brace of the ajax success function.

I often label end braces so I can keep track. E.g. //END ajax block

Use this, it will work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"passdata.php",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }                               //*****here was the error*****
            }); //END ajax
        }); //END form.change()
    }); //END document.ready
 </script>
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I noticed the skipped `;` in Rasclatt's response.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with BUTTON. The form consider button as type=submit
So when you pressed to the button it's a submit event was issued. please try the following code.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function onFormChange(){
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"passdata.php",
             data: $('form').serialize(),
             success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
             }  
          })
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "form > *" ).change(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            onFormChange()
         })  
         $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              onFormChange()
        });
    })
     </script>

</head>
<body>

<form >
<select class="dd1" name="state_chosen">
<option selected value = ""> Location </option>
<option value="Alabama" > US: Alabama   </option>
</select>
<select class="dd2" name="type">
<option selected value = ""> Type </option>
<option value="Plumber" > Plumber   </option>
</select>

<button name="page" value="1" >1</button>
<button name="page" value="2" >2</button>

</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No luck with your code.  I don't have to use "button".  The basic idea I want is to submit 3 independent variables to PHP/MySQL, one of which is page number.  As far as I can image, it is easier to submit the 3 variables together.

Comment: my code will work if you give a different names to the buttons. your question was : "Why I can not get response from php by using jQuery Ajax?" If you want help with other logic, edit your question

Answer (score 1):

Add a console.log to your success function so you can see what your PHP file is actually returning.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"passdata.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
               //$('#result').html(data);
            }  
       });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried `console.log(data)` (need a ";"?), but didn't see anything happening.  Why is that?

Comment: Assuming you checked the console (F12) and it still came up with nothing, then you probably aren't returning anything from your PHP page.

Comment: Got it.  Now I can see it with settings in Firebug.  I got something like `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: page in <b>P:\XAMPP\htdocs\passdata.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<div> <br>Nanny<br></div>`

Comment: Basically the same thing I saw in browser.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That error indicates your form is not being passed the $_POST['page'] variable. Add some validation to your PHP page to make sure your post variables are defined before trying to use them and you should be all good to go :)